# Powerbuilder PDF from blob

Tags: pdf, blob, powerbuilder

I tried to use the control "OLE database Blob" from Datawindow to show PDF directly from Oracle database. I used OLE class "AcroExch.Document.11 Adobe Acrobat Document". My problem is when I try to show old PDF. That PDF I can download directly from the database with database tool Connector "PL/SQL Developer" and open with Adobe Acrobat with any problem. But the new saved PDF row used the ole control I can´t open the PDF. [Error message from Adobe when trying to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9DrI.png)

But I don´t have the same problem when I run my PowerBuilder app ... Is work correctly. I check the DB and I see the new rows inserted with Ole controller have more data if I diff data between old and new PDF(I used same pdf file)

I ask if somebody know Why happen? Is it possible to access to data through code and process the blob data to convert the old pdf to the new pdf format?

Thanks,

Comment: Please check your English before submit your request!

Comment: Sorry, I correct the request.

Comment: Sorry- I'm not able to understand the question. My best guess- in trying to understand the question is that the OLE class you are using isn't compatible with the PDF. The English is not quite there for me.

Comment: Hi, I will try to describe the problem better. 

I created in  Datawindow one Control-> Ole Database Blob. 
The control has the OLE Class Description "AcroExch.Document.11: Adobe Acrobat Document".

The app created with PowerBuilder In the windows that have the Data window I can insert and update the PDF files. I can preview the pdf and open with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: But I see the Ole used in Control->Ole Database Blob  "AcroExch.Document.11: Adobe Acrobat Document" save in database column table with a special format, is not a clean PDF.  Add something to PDF data with causes it does not open properly when I try to download directly from DB.

Comment: I have old PDF saved in DB Those I can open directly from DB. That has the proper PDF format.

The problem here is I have pdf that are saved from an extern task. The task saves the data as clean PDF. That pdf Ole Database blob "AcroExch.Document.11: Adobe Acrobat Document" don't cant read. 

I search some code to open pdf from Blob put I should try to do directly without saving to a temporal file and show it. 

Thanks,

Comment: I think you are going to have to have a way to tell the two formats of blobs apart and use a different method of displaying them depending on which one it is. You might want to change how the external tasks saves the documents so that they are compatible with the OLE control.